# Returning a pointer to a structure

Tags: c

I'm trying to define a function that will return a pointer to a structure. I think I followed this correctly, ([Returning a struct pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702928/returning-a-struct-pointer)) but my code keeps complaining with this error message when I try to access the pointer's members, "error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete types".

Here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <string.h>   
#include <assert.h>  

struct lnode  
{  
  char* word;  
  int   line;  
  int   count;  
  struct lnode* nn;     /* nn = next node */  
};

struct lnode* newNode (char* word, int line) 
{
  struct lnode* newn = (struct lnode*) malloc(sizeof (struct lnode));
  if (!newn)
    return NULL;
  strcpy (newn->word, word);
  newn->line  = line;
  newn->count = 1;
  newn->nn    = NULL;
  return newn;
}

int main()
{
  char* p = "hello";
  struct lnode* head = newNode (p, 5);
  //the following lines are causing errors
  assert (!strcmp (head->word, p));     
  assert (head->line  == 5);
  assert (head->count == 1);
  assert (!head->nn);
  return 0;
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: i have a feeling that sth else is wrong...

Comment: The code you show is not the exactly how you have your code. The structure `lnode` is most likely defined in some other TU.

Comment: You are going to want to allocate memory for `word`. Your `strcpy` is going to bomb as soon as you can run this. And yes, please show the real code. This code appears to be fake. It's always disappointing to encounter fake code.

Comment: There is no problem in the code as it is here.

Comment: `#include <stdlib.h>` and don't cast return value of `malloc()`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan http://codepad.org/0xuEHDpN it already did :P `Segmentation Fault`.

Comment: Which line is the error on? Is it the struct in the struct?

Comment: [Please don't case the return value of `malloc()`, in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Comment: @user2083727: This code cannot possibly generate the error you quoted. Post real code.

Comment: @unwind why not cast?  I know it's not necessary for C, but it wont stop it working.

Comment: @Neil: There are lots of things in C that "won't stop it working". That still does not mean that overloading the code with unnecessary clutter is a good idea. There are several reasons not to cast the result of `malloc`, as well as no to use type names under `sizeof`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I didn't post the real code, because I thought it would be easier to find the bug, if the code was in one file. Nevertheless you've answered my question.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the obvious problem, that you missed to include `stdlib.h`, there is also a problem with how you handle strings.

In C, you (yes you), have to manage all the memory that you use for strings. This includes the memory pointed to by the member `word`.

You code does the following (after removing some fluff):

```
struct lnode* newn = malloc(...);
strcpy (newn->word, word);
```

Here, `newn->word` is uninitialized, so this will likely crash.

You will need allocate memory to store the string, for example by calling `malloc()` a second time:

```
struct lnode* newn = malloc(...);
newn->word = malloc(strlen(word) + 1);
strcpy (newn->word, word);
```

Answer (score 1):

The code must have access to the structure of `struct lnode`.

As Alok Save hinted, you probably have the declaration in another file (a header perhaps) and you forgot to `#include` it.